# How to get data from 2 columns, in different tables within Power Query, to sum into 1 column?

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

How to get data from 2 columns, in different tables within Excel Power Query, to sum into 1 column?
For example: Table names - Main_Company_HR_Data and Company1_HR_Data -- Fields I want to combine: Main_Company_HR_Data.Gross Company1_HR_Data.Gross.
Within the Data Model; I have established the connection to my data warehouse, and have linked the tables in Power Query as well. I added a column and attempted several suggestions from multiple sites. None work. I have been using: Calculate(SUMX(Main_Company_HR_Data.Gross))+ SUMX(Company1_HR_Data.Gross). And other iterations of the sort, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and the way I tackle it, is to make it as simple as possible.

Try this:

Enter this code as a formula, adding a column, in the tab which will have the field summed.

```
=LOOKUPVALUE('Company1_HR_Data'[Gross],'Company1_HR_Data'[Unique_ID],'Main_Company_HR_Data'[Unique_ID])
```

Create a column to sum the two in the same tab you created the above formula.

```
='Main_Company_HR_Data'[Gross]+'Company1_HR Data'[Gross]
```

Comment: That works!!!! Awesome. I searched high and low, creating DAX formulas and filters and going about it complexly. Thank you.

Comment: @PrChica - you should mark this as the answer. It helps BHasseltine.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick - I don't see that as an option for me to select, I definitely would if I could though :)